# $dist(A,B) = 0 \iff cl(A) \cap cl(B) \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is this property true $dist(A,B) = 0 \iff cl(A) \cap cl(B) \neq \emptyset$?

$\Leftarrow)$ If $dist(cl(A), cl(B)) = dist(A,B)$ then it is easy to see that $dist(cl(A), cl(B)) = 0 = dist(A,B)$ by taking any $x \in cl(A) \cap cl(B)$.

Is it true though that $dist(A,B) = 0 \Rightarrow cl(A) \cap cl(B) \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: No, consider the mirrored graph of $y = 1/x$, for instance

Comment: So only <=) holds? @interregno

Comment: I've expanded a little more on my answer when converse holds.

Answer (score 3):

Converse does not hold in general. Just take the disjoint graphs of $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions converging at same point at infinity, like $\frac{1}{x}$ and $- \frac{1}{x}$.

However, under some hypotheses on either $A$ or $B$ this can hold:

1. If our space $X$ has the Heine-Borel property (for instance, $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual metric), that is, compact sets are precisely the closed and bounded ones, and $A$ is bounded.
2. If $A$ is compact (equivalently sequentially compact).

Since without loss of generality we can replace $A$ by its closure, the former case reduces to the latter. Thus, suppose $A$ is compact and $\operatorname{dist}{(A, B)} = 0$. Thus we can pick pairs $(a_i, b_i)$ $a_i \in A, b_i \in B$ such that $d(a_i, b_i) \to 0$ for $i \to \infty$ (just pick $a_i, b_i$ s.t. $d(a_i, b_i) < 1/i$).

Then, since $A$ is compact, the $\{ a_i \}$ must have a convergent subsequence, which converges to $a^\ast \in A$. Now, by definition, $d(a^\ast, b_i) \to 0$ using the triangle inequality, but that means $a^\ast$ is a limit point of $B$.

Comment: Can you explain the counterexample in some more detail? If we define $d (A, B)$ to be the infimum of $d (a, b)$ for $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, then is the distance between the graphs of $y = \frac{1}{x}$ and $y = -\frac{1}{x}$ not identically $0$? (Assuming $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology.)

Comment: @K.Jiang It is a counterexample to $d(A, B) = 0 \implies \operatorname{cl}(A) \cap \operatorname{cl}(B) \neq \emptyset$, as both graphs are closed sets and disjoint.

Comment: Ah ok, I was confused because you mentioned that the *converse* does not hold, when it *is* true that ${\rm Cl} A \cap {\rm Cl} B \ne 0 \implies d (A, B) = 0$.